# Using 'AND' instead of '&' when filtering a dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was checking out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values) and had a quick follow-up question. The answer says that in case of multiple conditions parentheses are required since operator "&" is more binding than comparison operators:

```py
df.loc[(df['column_name'] >= A) & (df['column_name'] <= B)]
```

And missing parentheses here will result in 'value ambiguous' error.

Looking at [operator precedence rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) I noticed that `and` is less binding than comparison operators. In this case can the same be re-written like this?

```py
df.loc[df['column_name'] >= A and df['column_name'] <= B]
```

Comment: It cannot be used in this case since `and` will attempt to treat the operands as `bool`s, causing their magic method `__bool__` to run. It will return the error "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().".

Comment: `&` operator is not an equivalent to `and`.  `&` is a bit-wise operator. Maybe you are thinking of `&&` (boolean and) in other languages, python does not have this. Or rather, it has `and`

Comment: Yeah, this is where I got confused. Now I noticed that one is boolean and the other is bitwise. Good to know. Explains a lot of issues I've been having.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco While `&` is normally the bitwise operator, it is overloaded in DataFrames and Series to do element-wise operations, either bitwise or logical operations depending on the context. In the case of `bool`s, it does the logical and operation.